# Is it a good idea to populate routes dynamically from database in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a auth system where I have all the permissions in the database. I call them from db and process (authenticate user permissions) in a middleware. Thus each time I add a route into the routes I have to add the same as permission to the database.

```
$permissions = \DB::table('permissions')->get();
$router = app()->make('router');

foreach($permissions as $permission){
    $router->get($permission->path, $permission->controller)->name($permission->name);
}
```

I am wondering what disadvantages would it have to generate routes from (DB) my permissions table ?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly you have 1 route per user permission?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman no it is actually permission per role. But it is in a many-to-many relation.

Comment: Why not use standardized routes, and use middleware Policy checks (you check the users role inside the policy functions) to authenticate users? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: i am using `$gate->define($permission->route, function($user) use ($permission){
                    return $user->hasRole($permission->roles);
                 });`